# What exactly does 'Type Body Length' mean in Swiftlint?

Tags: swift, swiftlint

We just added Swiftlint to our project and we want to follow all the rules but I'm not sure what's meant by 'type_body_length' warning. I'm not a native english speaker so I find it a bit confusing.

There is a rule for file length aswell so how do they differ? What falls under this definition?

[image]

Comment: Am I getting downvoted for not having a grasp of the english language? That seems quite harsh. Type body is probably something I would understand in my own language but Type and Body are very generic to me. Type could mean anything really, body should mean the major code block I guess. But if this only means the entire length of a class for example how does this differ from file length? Are extensions "escaped" from this rule?.

Comment: type_body_length violation means that the class has too many lines in it. I dont think it counts extensions

Comment: Thank you. A clear answer and definition I was looking for. You could post this comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[type_body_length](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/blob/master/Rules.md#type-body-length) violation means that the class has too many lines in it. I dont think it counts extensions, comments or whitespace

> Type name should only contain alphanumeric characters, start with an uppercase character and span between 3 and 40 characters in length.

The [rules](https://realm.github.io/SwiftLint/rule-directory.html) documentation linked here and above also gives examples of what would and wouldn't be accepted (Triggering & Non Triggering). - Edit suggested by @GoodSp33d, thanks

Comment: @andromedainiative Probably also a good idea to refer to the Triggering & NonTriggering examples in the documentation. If one cannot understand from the text (true for me as well) the examples help.

Comment: Thanks, I wont post them all here but i'll add a note to refer to them as the documentation will be updated over time

Comment: I actually don't understand the difference in the examples. At all.

Comment: A Type is a enum, class, struct, protocol etc. Something you define. The body of that type cannot be too long.

Comment: Kind of strange that it seems to be better to have a load full extensions than one class structured with pragma marks.